# Comment Box above or below ?

Tags: placement, comments

I am creating a commenting block on my website. I just want to know which is the better way to put the comment box above the list of comments or below it ?
[image]

Show i place the Comments above or below the comments ?

this is the page layout

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, people are commenting about the restaurant rather than responding to comments about the restaurant. So there is no requirement for someone to read the existing comments before adding their own.

In fact people would probably find it quite tedious to trawl through all the comments and would thus be less likely to add their own if the comments were at the bottom.

So I would say comment box *above*.

Answer (score 5):

In the general case, you could argue that the comment box placement should depend on the order comments are displayed in: if the most recent comment is on top, the next comment will be above that one, so put the comment box there; if the most recent comment is on bottom, go bottom.

And this goes well with Mongus' answer - if comments are a conversation, oldest-first and box on bottom may be preferable; if comments stand on their own and recent is better, as your case may be, newest-first and box on top could be a better fit.